# Getting NPE in AsyscTask posEcecute method while getting view

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I am new to android development and this is my first application.
I am using Fragments and Adapters to display the Tabs. This is Tab2 (Downoad Details) fragment code, in which on select of Tab, I am calling a webserive which gets the data from database and sets it in the view. Everything is working and I am getting response from WS in Jason. I am parsing this Jason data and wants to display in tabLayout. While display I am getting NPE.

Few post have suggested to use `setUserVisibleHint` but I am not able to achieve desired output with this.

**Please suggest what should I do so that when I select the Tab2 (Downoad Details) or swipes to this Tab, my WS gets called and data would be displayed on the Tab page.**

Below is My Activity

```
 @SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class DownloadStatusActivity extends FragmentActivity  implements ActionBar.TabListener  {


ProgressDialog prgDialog1;
TextView errorMsg1;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;
// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "Download Overview", "Downoad Details"  };


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dwnld_status_activity);

    String value1= getIntent().getStringExtra("loccodeselected");
    String value2= getIntent().getStringExtra("bccodeselected");
    String value3= getIntent().getStringExtra("bmselected");
    TextView dwndActlbl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dwndActlbl);
    dwndActlbl.setText(Html.fromHtml("Download Status for " + value1 +","+value2 +","+value3+ "is as below: </b>"));

     // Initilization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        


    ////passing data to fragement start//
    //bundle
    Bundle bundle =new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("value1",value1);
    bundle.putString("value2",value2);
    bundle.putString("value3",value3);

    DSFragment frag_in = new DSFragment();
    DDFragement frag_out = new DDFragement();

    frag_in.setArguments(bundle);
    frag_out.setArguments(bundle);
    mAdapter.addFrag(frag_in," ");
    mAdapter.addFrag(frag_out," ");
    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    ///////////////

    ///passing data to fragement end///


    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     * */
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });


    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // on tab selected
    // show respected fragment view
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }


}
```

Below is the Fargement code.

```
public class DDFragement extends Fragment {
JsonArray arrayFromString=new JsonArray(); 
private ProgressDialog    prgDialog1;
View rootView=null;

private boolean isViewShown = false;


@Override

public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);


    if (getView() != null ) {
        isViewShown = true;
        // fetchdata() contains logic to show data when page is selected mostly asynctask to fill the data

    } else {
        isViewShown = false;
    }


}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {






    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dd_fragement, container, false);
    String loc="";
    String bc="";String bm="";

    if(!isViewShown)
    {
    if(getArguments()!=null)
    {
      loc = getArguments().getString("value1");    
      bc = getArguments().getString("value2");  
      bm = getArguments().getString("value3");  
    }


        new invokegetDwnldDetailDataAsynTask().execute(loc,bc,bm);
    }
    return rootView;
}




/*******Implmentation of Async Task******************/
class invokegetDwnldDetailDataAsynTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, JsonArray> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
            prgDialog1 = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        prgDialog1.setMessage("Loading Download Details. Please wait...");
        prgDialog1.setIndeterminate(false);
        prgDialog1.setCancelable(false);
        prgDialog1.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * @return 
     * */
    protected JsonArray doInBackground(String...  dwnparams) {

        String loc = dwnparams[0];
        String bc = dwnparams[1];
        String bm = dwnparams[2];


        RequestParams reqparams = new RequestParams();
        reqparams.put("loccodeselected", loc);
        reqparams.put("bccodeselected", bc);
        reqparams.put("bmselected", bm);

        // Show Progress Dialog 
        //prgDialog1.show();

        // Make RESTful webservice call using AsyncHttpClient object
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.get("http://localhost:8081/useraccount/queries/fetchdwnDetailStatus",reqparams ,new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            // When the response returned by REST has Http response code '200'
             @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            @Override
             public void onSuccess(String response) {
                // Hide Progress Dialog
                // prgDialog1.hide();
                 try {
                         // JSON Object
                         JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                       if(jObj!=null)
                       {
                           System.out.println("RESPONSE1===>"+jObj.getString("downloadDetails"));


                           JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
                           arrayFromString = jsonParser.parse((String) jObj.getString("downloadDetails")).getAsJsonArray();
                           System.out.println("RESPONSE2===>"+arrayFromString);
                         }

                         // Else display error message
                         else{
                            // errorMsg1.setText(jObj.getString("error_msg"));
                             Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "ERROR SOME", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         }




                 } catch (JSONException e) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                     Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Error Occured [Server's JSON response might be invalid]!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     e.printStackTrace();

                 }
             }
             // When the response returned by REST has Http response code other than '200'
             @Override
             public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error,
                 String content) {
                 // Hide Progress Dialog
                // prgDialog1.hide();
                 // When Http response code is '404'
                 if(statusCode == 404){
                     Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Requested resource not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 } 
                 // When Http response code is '500'
                 else if(statusCode == 500){
                     Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong at server end", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 } 
                 // When Http response code other than 404, 500
                 else{
                     Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Unexpected Error occcured! [Most common Error: Device might not be connected to Internet or remote server is not up and running]", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }
             }
         });
        return arrayFromString;





    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(JsonArray arrayFromString1) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        prgDialog1.dismiss();

                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */


               if (arrayFromString1 != null) { 
                   int count=0;
                     TableLayout tl;
                        tl = (TableLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ddfragment_table);

                     for (int i=0;i<arrayFromString.size();i++){ 
                      // System.out.println("array==>"+arrayFromString.get(i).toString());


                       TableRow tr1 = new TableRow(getActivity());
                        if(count%2!=0) tr1.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                        tr1.setId(i);

                        // tr.setBackgroundResource(Color.MAGENTA);
                         tr1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                                     //TEXTVIEWS********
                         TextView tv1 = new TextView(getActivity());
                         String textLabel="";
                         tv1.setText(textLabel );  //seetting first response in cell

                         tv1.setId(i);
                         tv1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                         tv1.setTextSize(15);
                         tv1.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                         tr1.addView(tv1);

                        tl.addView(tr1, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                         count++;  
                   } 
                } 

           }

}
```

}

The error is onpostExecute() at line  `tl = (TableLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ddfragment_table)`;
Error: NullPointerException.. Attempet to invoke virtual method..findViewbyId(int) on a null obj refrence

Comment: There probably is something wrong with your JSON (arrayFromString). On what object do you get the NPE? Check your stacktrace and use the debugger mode to see what you get in your JSON response.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for response. I am getting NPE onpostExecute() at code  TableLayout tl;
 tl = (TableLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ddfragment_table);

Comment: Well this probably means that the program could not find TableLayout tl; tl = (TableLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ddfragment_table), so check that te name is correctly written in your layou ->: ddfragment_table.

Comment: @JediCate, the name is correct, the problem which I understood is onpostexecute() is getting called before onCreateView where I have created a View from LayoutInflater. So getting NPE. I am not sure, how can I make View available in setUserVisibleHint just before invoking AsyncTask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rootView in Your oncreateView in the fragment is not the same rootview that is class member. Replace:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dd_fragement, container, false);
```

with:

```
rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dd_fragement, container, false);
```

By the way, thats why it is preferable to name class members like this: View mRootView;

Comment: Thanks for correcting that. I do able to display data of tab 1(Download Overview) and Tab2(Downoad Details). But I can see progress dialog of Tab2 whenever i comes to Tab1. Also the data in Tab2 keep on adding up everytime i comes to Tab2. Please help